# Regex Expression Incorrectly Validating Input

Tags: python, regex, validation

I'm writing a regular expression to validate a phone number in North American format. I am checking for the following conditions: `1234567890`, `123.456.7890`, `123-456-7890`, `(123) 456-7890`. The values are read in from a .csv file.

I believe the regular expression I've written should account for the above instances, as well as accounting for instances where the sets of digits are separated by spaces. I've checked this on www.regex101.com and it seems to validate, or not validate, correctly.

Here is the segment of code that validates the value:

```
    elif tempList[0] == 'phone':
        matchObj = re.match('[(]?\d{3}[-.)]?[ ]?\d{3}[-.]?[ ]?\d{4}', tempList[1])
        print(tempList[1])
        if matchObj:
            print('phone = Right!')
```

The value for `tempList[0]` is `phone` and the value for `tempList[1]` is `1234567890000000`. When I run the script on my terminal, I get `phone = Right!` printed, which should not be printed. When I check this regular expression on regex101.com, it says that the string is not validated, which is what I expect. This is written in python3.

Comment: Use `re.match('[(]?\d{3}[-.)]?[ ]?\d{3}[-.]?[ ]?\d{4}$', tempList[1])` as `re.match` only searches at the start of the string and does not require a full string match

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression that `re.match` will search the string in it's entirety. That makes sense, thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: In cases of validation, it's better to use 3rd party libraries. have a look at https://pypi.org/project/phonenumbers/

Comment: Check this one https://regex101.com/r/t9y30a/2 It also parses into 3 groups so you don't need any further parsing to get the whole number without special chars.